# How to find a wireless usb adapter supporting managed + ap mode combination?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, adapter

I'm looking for a wireless usb adapters that could act both as a wireless client and an access point **at once.** It's almost impossible to tell by looking at vendors promotional material if any given model supports this mode of operation. In linux I could just run:

```
iw phy0 info | grep -E '{.* managed.* AP.*}|{.* AP.* managed.*}'
```

to tell if a wireless card supports this mode of operation, but I can't find any meaningful keywords to look for when researching a wireless adapter online to determine if it supports this. Do you know how to find a wireless adapter that supports this mode of operation online?

Comment: Try looking for a chipset for which you have the drivers with simultaneous AP/client support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best resource I know of for low-level details of Wi-Fi devices and chipsets is [WikiDevi](https://WikiDevi.com). However, I'm not sure if that record that kind of information.

Please note that what a given hardware chipset supports may vary based on how it's integrated into a card/device, what firmware/microcode the chipset is running, and what driver you're using for it.

In general I'd look for devices that use Atheros (a.k.a. "Qualcomm Atheros", "QCA") chipsets. Atheros has been especially friendly with open source, and the ath9k drivers are some of the most flexible drivers out there, so even though I don't know for sure that this is supported under any ath9k supported chipsets, that's where I'd start looking.

I've known some Broadcom-based chipsets that support both modes simultaneously under some OSes, but I don't know about current offerings under Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Redpine specifies this as co-existence.

```
Wireless Co-Existence Modes
    * Wi-Fi Access Point + Wi-Fi Client
    * Wi-Fi Client + Bluetooth Classic (EDR v 2.1)
    * Wi-Fi Client + Bluetooth Low Energy 
    * Wi-Fi Access Point + BLE
```

Broadcom/Cypress calls it APSTA (Access Point + Station).